# Call to Web API - Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

I am trying to avoid the NULL and show the unique values from the API response in to the dropdown. I am trying the below

```
 export class ReportingFilterComponent implements OnInit {

 ShipmentList: ShipmentByProject[];
 shipTo= [];

 entityUrl = 'ShipmentDetail/GetByReportingProject?repPrj=000634';

 constructor(service: DataService) {

 service.get<ShipmentByProject[]>(this.entityUrl).subscribe(x => {this.ShipmentList = x });

 this.shipTo = this.ShipmentList.filter(_ => _.customer_shipto_name);
 const uniqueShipTo = new Set(this.shipTo);
```

And using the uniqueShipTo in the html like

```
<div class="dx-fieldset">
    <div class="dx-field">
        <div class="dx-field-label">ShipTo Account</div>
        <div class="dx-field-value">
            <dx-select-box [dataSource]="uniqueShipTo" ></dx-select-box>
        </div>
        </div>
```

But I get error

`4200/vendor.js:43416 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined`

The API call works and I get the response back but not sure why it says `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The challenge we got here is the asynchronous nature of the HTTP call.
Your code does the following at the moment:

- You initialize `shipTo` with `undefined` (implicitly through not defining a value)
- You send out the HTTP request and *register*  the callback function, that should be called when the response comes back.
- You try to access the `filter()` method on `shipTo` which is still `undefined`
- The HTTP response comes back asynchronously and the subscribe callback will be executed – but too late.

To avoid this, you need to trigger the transformation logic (the stuff at the bottom) when the data is there – not earlier.
The easiest way to do so is to put it into the subscribe callback as well.
However, with the power of RxJS you can solve this more elegantly:

```
service.get<ShipmentByProject[]>(this.entityUrl).pipe(
  filter(_ => _.customer_shipto_name),
  map(filteredList => new Set(filteredList))
).subscribe(uniqueShipTo => {
  // you now have uniqueShipTo available and can work with it
});
```

So you now have an Observable that performs a HTTP request and emits the Set of unique entries.
In order to bring this to the template, there's two ways.
First idea is to just write the data to a component property and access it from the template. that's almost the way you already did.

The second idea is a bit more elegant and avoid the `subscribe()` in the component.
We omit the `subscribe()` and put the whole Observable into a component property:

```
import { filter, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

// ...
uniqueShipTo$: Observable<Set<ShipmentByProject>>;

// ...
this.uniqueShipTo$ = service.get<ShipmentByProject[]>(this.entityUrl).pipe(
  filter(_ => _.customer_shipto_name),
  map(filteredList => new Set(filteredList))
);
```

Then in the template you can use Angular's `AsyncPipe` to subscribe to this Observable:

```html
<div class="dx-fieldset">
    <div class="dx-field">
        <div class="dx-field-label">ShipTo Account</div>
        <div class="dx-field-value">
            <dx-select-box *ngIf="uniqueShipTo$ | async as shipTo" [dataSource]="shipTo" ></dx-select-box>
        </div>
        </div>
```

The key here is the `ngIf` which removes the select box until no data is available.

Comment: Thank you for the detailsed answer. But I need to use the reponse data back in different components, if I am using the filter with in the API call I wont be getting anything else apart from `customer_shipto_name`??

Comment: You can put the whole operator chain from the component into the service. Your service can have the general method (`service.get()`)  and a more specialized one that fetches the same but transforms it to a unique set of shipTo addresses.
If you then want to cache the response so you save HTTP calls, the `shareReplay()` operator is your friend.

Comment: Can you please show me the example of how I can deal with Cached Result to remove null and make it unique? I updated the question with what I tried